# Count distinct values separated by a comma

Tags: sql, database, oracle, count, distinct

I have this table called `test`

| id | my_list |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aa//11, aa//34, ab//65 |
| 2 | bb//43, bb//43, be//54 |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | cc//76 |

I want to count the distinct values in `my_list`, where each item in the list is separated by a comma. In this case:

- `id=1` will have `3` distinct values
- `id=2` will have `2` distinct values as `bb//43` as shown up twice, thus 2 distinct values
- `id=3` will have `0` distinct values as it as an empty list
- `id=4` will have `1` since there is only 1 item in the list

I want to do this in pure SQL and not using a custom made procedure. I tried with the statement below but it is showing 1.

```
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT my_list) as my_count
FROM test;
```

Expected result:

| id | my_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |

Comment: Normalize your schema. See ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) (Spoiler: Yes, it is.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn your list into table to `count distinct` inside it. With [`json_table`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm), for example.

> ```
> with a(id, my_list) as (
>   select 1, 'aa//11, aa//34, ab//65' from dual union all
>   select 2, 'bb//43, bb//43, be//54' from dual union all
>   select 3, null from dual union all
>   select 4, 'cc//76' from dual
> )
> select
>   id
>   , (
>       select count(distinct val)
>       from json_table(
>         /*Replace comma with quotes and comma: ','
>           And wrap with array brackets
>         */
>         '[''' || regexp_replace(my_list, '\s*,\s*', ''',''') || ''']'
>         , '$[*]'
>         columns ( val varchar(20) path '$')
>       )
>     ) as cnt
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | CNT
> -: | --:
>  1 |   3
>  2 |   2
>  3 |   0
>  4 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0243a8d1c1cc6ad11f3d3c6d0c416f61)*